# Why do my tableau diagrams disappear when I change the data source?

Tags: tableau-api, datasource

I changed the data source of a tableau workbook and after that all of my diagrams disappeared. I do not have any missing measures or dimensions. Can anyone explain why this happens / how to fix the problem?

Comment: do your worksheets contain any kind of filters? such as filtering year = 2019 while your new datasource has data only from 2020 on...

Comment: How did you change the data source? Just changing it will not make tableau recognise that you want to use the new source for the existing visualisation. Did you use the "Replace Data Source" menu to *tell* tableau you wanted to use the new source?